# How do I use 1x scancodes as argument in SendInput

Tags: c, .net, sendinput, interopservices, scancodes

I'm using SendInput() (using InteropServices, C#) with scancodes as argument. However, I don't manage to send combinations using R-ALT. I'm using Mac with Bootcamp and the R-ALT scancode is registered as 1x38 (R-ALT + L-Control) but I can't use 138 (1x38?) as a scancode argument (ushort/int).

Error message is just "The name x38 does not exist in the current context".

How do I properly use scancodes like 138 as argument in SendInput()?

Comment: Right-Alt is an extended key, scan code 0xE0 0x38.  So set wScan to 0x38 (not x38), dwFlags to KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY to tell it to expect the 0xE0 prefix.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant, it works to synthesize the extended key combination. My issue now is that I don't understand how to release the extended key properly. Earlier I sent 4 keys e.g shift keydown, 6 keydown, 6 keyup, shift keyup (simulation of "&") but when changing keydown to the extended key, the key is pressed until I reboot. Any idea?

Comment: I'd guess you forgot to turn both flags on, set  dwFlags to `KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP`